# immutable item got from vector[]

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, reference, g++

I have a question regarding vector [] operator in C++.

```
vector<stack<T>> myStackVec;
ops...
...
...
```

This code does not modify `myStackVec`:

```
stack<T> temp = myStackVec.at(stackPos);
cout << "removing " << temp.top() << endl;
```

This code does modify `myStackVec` through modifying `temp`:

```
stack<T> *temp = &myStackVec[stackPos];
temp->push(item);
```

[] operator returns a reference, why code snippet 1 does not work? Is `temp` in code1 a copy?

Comment: It is a copy. You did not declare it as a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
stack<T> temp = myStackVec.at(stackPos);
```

will make a copy of stack, then `temp.push_back` will operate on the copied stack, you need reference instead:

```
stack<T> &temp = myStackVec.at(stackPos);
temp.push_back(item);
```

or simply:

```
myStackVec.at(stackPos).push_back(item);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is `temp` in code1 a copy?

Yes.

Make it a reference for this to work.

```
stack<T> &temp = myStackVec.at(stackPos);
cout << "removing " << temp.top() << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

Think for a second what type `stack<T> temp` is. Tip: it is *not* a reference.